# Clear Cookie in React Native Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, cookies, azure-active-directory, expo

We are developing an mobile application with react native. We would like to use the Azure Active Directory(Azure Ad) authentication.

The login flow is smooth with this example: https://github.com/shedaltd/react-native-azure-ad-2. But we cannot clear the cookie for the sign out flow therefore when the user click the login button again, he do not need to insert his email and password again.

We tried to use
`RCTNetworking.clearCookies(() => {})`
It works in Android but not in IOS devices.

May i know is there any other method we can clear the cookies in IOS or we should not use EXPO to generate our react native project?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the iOS implementation is not working as expected. Replace your current cookies management solution with [@react-native-cookies/cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-cookies/cookies). Also, and instead of clearing out all cookies, you should send [Send a sign-out request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request) which will clear all required cookies.